# How to Install VTK (with Python Wrapper) on Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL)

Tags: rhel, compiling, rpm, cmake

A program I need to compile is dependent on VTK v5.4+ with Python Wrapper. VTK is not in the standard YUM repo's.

How can I install this dependency?

I am running RHEL 7 under developer subscription.

Answer (score 2):

### Installing VTK Dependencies

Ensure gcc and g++ are installed:

```sh
yum install gcc
yum install gcc-c++
```

Ensure cmake is installed:

```sh
yum install cmake
```

Ensure OpenGL modules are installed

```sh
yum install mesa-libGL
yum install mesa-libGL-devel
```

([mesa-libGL is an MIT licensed implementation of OpenGL which RHEL uses](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/56301))

Ensure X11_Xt_LIB is installed:

```sh
yum install libXt-devel
```

Ensure Python Libraries are installed:

```sh
yum install python-devel
```

Ensure NumPy is installed

```sh
yum whatprovides numpy  # this will provide a list of package names  
sudo yum install <package name>
```

example : `sudo yum install numpy-1.7.1-11.el7.x86_64`

Ensure TCL is installed

```sh
sudo yum install tcl
```

### Installing VTK (with Python Wrapper)

[Here is the reference that was used for this step](http://www.cb.uu.se/~johan/vtk/installing_vtk_on_rhel6.txt)

1. Install latest tarball source code from http://www.vtk.org/download/, e.g.  `VTK-7.0.0.tar.gz`
2. Create the following VTK file structure:

   ```sh
   mkdir $HOME/VTK
   ```
3. extract the tarball contents into the $HOME/VTK folder:

   ```sh
   tar -xvf ~/Downloads/VTK-X.X.X.tar.gz -C ~/VTK
   ```

   - replace `X.X.X` with your version number
   - make sure `~/Downloads/` contains your tarball
4. move the contents of `VTK-X.X.X` folder directly into `$HOME/VTK/` and remove the folder `VTK-X.X.X`
5. Modify your `.bashrc` file

   - Open .bashrc:

     ```sh
     sudo nano ~/.bashrc
     ```
   - Add `export VTK_ROOT=$HOME/VTK/` to the file
   - run the command `source $HOME/.bashrc`
6. Build VTK with CMake

   - ```sh
     cd $VTK_ROOT
     mkdir build
     cd build
     cmake ../ -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DBUILD_TESTING=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DVTK_WRAP_PYTHON=ON
     ```

     Note: if this command says there is no CMakeLists.txt, then the path '../' does not lead to the folder with the extracted data. Make sure you completed the movement of the files specified in step 4.
   - ```sh
     make -j5
     ```

     This will take a *while* the first time
   - ```sh
     make test
     ```

     Tests to make sure everything installed properly, this too takes a while

     - The result should be similar to `99% tests passed, 7 tests failed out of 1448`. The fewer failures the better, however.
     - If many of them are failing, it may be because the build folder is not surrounded by the source folders, e.g. `Accelerators`, `Charts`, etc...

### Python Wrapper

Modify your `.bashrc` file

- ```sh
  sudo nano ~/.bashrc
  ```
- Add the following lines to the file

  ```sh
  export PYTHONPATH=$VTK_ROOT/build/Wrapping/Python/:$VTK_ROOT/build/bin:$VTK_ROOT/build/lib
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$VTK_ROOT/build/bin:$VTK_ROOT/build/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
  ```

Test installation to make sure it worked

- ```sh
  python
  import vtk
  ```

  Assuming the `import vtk` command did not complain to you, you're all set.

Comment: after install, run: `sudo ldconfig` to update ld_library, instead of export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Answer (score 1):

A better alternative to building it from source is to install a repository that includes it.  EPEL actually has it.

Download the latest epel-release*.rpm from `http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/`

Install epel-release rpm:

```
rpm -Uvh epel-release*.rpm
```

Install the VTK package:

```
yum install vtk
```

Comment: The main problem with building packages from source is that they are not managed by your system's package manager and eventually may cause conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me building from binary on Centos 7 / RHEL is

Step 1

```
yum install epel-release
```

Step 2

```
yum install vtk
```